# using variables as strings in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I use variables to represent string values in MySQL?  The stored procedure below has two variables `@varname` and `@file1`.  It also uses `concat()` to create a string from `@file1`, but none of these string values is populating properly into the script.  (The query is not loading results and the outfile is not being created.)  How can I fix this code so that it works?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `parse_descriptions`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `parse_descriptions`()
BEGIN

SET @varname='something';
SET @file1= concat('D:/mypath/','@varname');

select d.id, d.term, d.conceptid from dtablename as d 
where term like '%@varname%' 
into outfile concat('@file1','_test.txt') 
fields terminated by '\t'
optionally enclosed by ""
lines terminated by '\r\n'
;

END$$

CALL `parse_descriptions`()$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `parse_descriptions`$$
```

Comment: You should just say it like `SET @file1= concat('D:/mypath/',@varname);` by removing the quote around the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

other than misplacing quotes in few places around the parameters as I have already commented the biggest problem is you are trying to use variable in `select ...into outfile` command which can only be done through `prepared statement`. A sample included below [tested and it works fine]. You can make the changes accordingly per your needs.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `parse_descriptions`()
BEGIN
SET @varname='harikas';
SET @file1= concat('D:/SO_Test/',@varname, '_test.txt');

SET @sql = CONCAT('select * from teachers where username like ''%', @varname, '%'' into outfile ''', @file1 , '''');
select @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
```

Prepared statement going to generate a query like below

```
select * from teachers where username like '%harikas%' into outfile 
'D:/SO_Test/harikas_test.txt'
```

Call the procedure

```
call parse_descriptions()
```

**EDIT:** You are missing a `'` at end of the line. Your modified procedure should looks like

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `parse_descriptions`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `parse_descriptions`()
BEGIN

SET @varname='something';
SET @file1= concat('D:/mypath/',@varname, '_test.txt');

SET @sql = concat('select d.id, d.term, d.cid from dtablename as d where term like ''%', @varname, '%'' into outfile ''', @file1 , ''' fields terminated by ''\t'' optionally enclosed by "" lines terminated by ''\r\n''');
select @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
```

Comment: It is working now, so I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @CodeMed, modified your procedure. take a look in edited answer.

Comment: Thank you again.  It takes a very long time to run the procedure, though the select statement itself takes only a few seconds when run in raw form.  Why is this approach so slow?

Comment: @CodeMed, should it not be? there are 3 operations involved 1. fetching data through select query -> 2. prepare the statement and 3. write the resultant data to disk file (the slowest one probably depends upon number of rows to write to disk file).

Comment: There are only 2 rows in the test output file but it takes 7 minutes to run the procedure.  When I do the same thing without a procedure or variables, it all happens in less than 30 seconds using the same small test query.

Comment: @CodeMed, that's strange cause I tested before posting as answer and didn't face any such issue. Why not post a separate question for the same with all relevant data. If you would like me to take a look as well; post the link of the question here as comment.

Comment: Thanks.  The exercise of trying to write a question caused me to see the problem was that I was using `@varname` instead of `_paramname` when creating `@file1`.  It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code. Think you had the quotes wrong in a couple places

```
SET @varname='something';
SET @file1= concat('D:/mypath/',@varname);   --here

select d.id, d.term, d.conceptid from dtablename as d 
where term like concat('%', @varname, '%') -- here
into outfile concat(@file1,'_test.txt')  -- here
fields terminated by '\t'
optionally enclosed by ""
lines terminated by '\r\n'
;
```